# How am I able to use/edit navigation bar features when I don't have a reference?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently learning iOS development and I'm confused on how I was able to edit/use my navigation bar even though I don't have an IBOutlet?

Code:

```swift
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextfield: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "⚡️FlashChat" //edited the title of the navigation bar for this view
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true //hid a button

    }

    @IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBAction func logoutPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you can access it from navigation controller if your view controller has it, like this self.navigationController?.navigationBar

Comment: Is that the default from the UIViewController class?

Comment: yes, look through all properties and methods of UIViewController, Command+Left Mouse Click on class

Comment: I see ok ty for your help

Answer (score 0):

call `setupNavBarAttributes()` function from `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool` located in **Appdelegate.swift** file and observe the changes.

It will customize the **UINavigationBar** of every **UIViewController**s in your App.

```
func setupNavBarAttributes() {

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .default
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .cyan  // change color of the buttons of navigationbar
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .blue  // change front color of navigationbar
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage() // make disappear the bottom shadow of navigationbar
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default) // make background to a blank/empty image

        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 19, weight: .bold)]  // change the font color of navigation title

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigation bars are not part of the UIViewController, they are actually part of the parent UINavigationController, which encapsulates your UIViewController. So, when you access the navigationItem, you're essentially accessing the navigation controller's bar.

Read more about container view controllers [here](https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers).